# Problema com grunt-uncss

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grunt

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer a leitura de um arquivo .CSHTML com grunt-uncss, pois pesquisei e tentei e até agora não tive nenhum resultado..

Comment: Por que você está usando um pacote do Node em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Para melhorar a velocidade do meu site, removendo redundancia e css desnecessario do bootstrap

Comment: Bom, a chance de algo assim funcionar é mínima. Pelo que eu entendi da leitura do pacote, ele lê apenas HTML.

Comment: Descobri que ele le CSHTML, porém quero que leia dinamicamente, junto com meu localhost, exemplo: http://localhost:50514/Home a documentação se encontra aqui https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#start-of-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme [este comentario no GitHub](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/66#issuecomment-37796186) consegui resolver meu problema o codigo ficou assim:

```javascript
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        uncss: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'Content/home.css': ['index.html']
                },
                options: {
                    urls: ['MinhaPagina/Home']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');

    // Default tasks.
    grunt.registerTask('uncss', ['uncss']);
};
```

**EDIT**: Precisa existir um `arquivo.html` vazio, que no meu caso é o `index.html` para o funcionamento